# Gitlab CI CD Production Config Unkown Keys

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Gitlab CI CD Pipeline fails for the following yml with the error

```
obs:production config contains unknown keys: type
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: node:latest

before_script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl

stages:
    - production

production:
    type: deploy
    stage: production
    image: ruby:latest
    script:
        - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_PRODUCTION --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
    only:
        - main
```

Comment: Remove type:deploy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Job-defined types are deprecated and [have been removed in GitLab 15](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#job-defined-type). Use `stage:` instead.